# Controlling Gunicorn in a new ssh session

Tags: django, linux, ubuntu, ssh, gunicorn

I am using Gunicorn to power Django application on a remote server (ubuntu), to which I connect by ssh. Once Gunicorn has  started the status log pops up showing you what is going on and such. However when I close my ssh session and reconnect later on I cant seem to reopen the process without killing Gunicorn and rebooting the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i understand your issue correctly... 
When running django/gunicorn usually it is helpful to use some tools to control the processes. One really good option to do so is the use of supervisord:
http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/deploy.html#supervisor

If you just want to run processes directly and being able to (dis-)connect - generally [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) is a good option.
It allows you to to disconnect an ssh-session while leaving your 'virtual?' terminals running.
Just re-ssh to your server and reconnect using:

```
screen -xr
```